# How to connect to Redis server from Reis cli?

Tags: redis

I am using Windows 10 x64, I try

```
cd /d C:\Program Files\Redis
redis-cli -h 192.168.50.221 -a mpit@2018 -p 6739 ping
```

[image]

but cannot connect. How to connect to Redis server?

Comment: are you looking for the `INFO` command?

Comment: How to use/call `INFO` command? It is Redis for Windows, it run as a Windows service. I try

Comment: you just type in INFO in the cli

Comment: https://gist.github.com/donhuvy/adc212a78f19ea7a3b428b71904e3bdc and https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/1328316/95283813-d6f5b980-0886-11eb-972f-8fe7db069af1.png https://gist.github.com/donhuvy/e4a5a0c12479a15610240a6a7d31709f

Comment: see interactive mode section here https://redis.io/topics/rediscli